# How to check in VBA code if a computer is connected to Bloomberg

Tags: vba, bloomberg

I am calling a function - calcReturnForecast.updateForecast that starts a piece of code fetching values from Bloomberg. the following piece initiates the Bloomberg COM Control-

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set session = New blpapicomLib2.session
session.QueueEvents = True
session.Start
session.OpenService ("//blp/refdata")
Set refdataservice = session.GetService("//blp/refdata")
End Sub
```

---

But, if a computer is not connected to Bloomberg this naturally gives an error.
How can I put a check before calling the function that check if a system is connected to Bloomberg? If not , then it just skips this Function.

Comment: Add an error handler command like `On Error Goto...` to jump at the end of the function?

Comment: So, even my using an Error Handler, it is tries to execute the first line and then there is an error: 
Option Explicit
Private session As blpapicomLib2.session
Dim refdataservice As blpapicomLib2.Service

' Instantiate the Bloomberg COM Control
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

Set session = New blpapicomLib2.session
session.QueueEvents = True
session.Start

session.OpenService ("//blp/refdata")
Set refdataservice = session.GetService("//blp/refdata")

End Sub

Comment: Is it possible to some how check if .exe file for Bloomberg is on the PC for not. Then I could write something like If IsProcessRunning("Bloomberg.EXE") = False Then GoTo End Sub Else.....